# Looping through object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
if(properties != undefined)
{
    foreach(key in properties)
    {
        dialogProperty.key = property[key];
    }
    alert(dialogProperty.close);
}
```

How can I achieve/fix the above code? I think the above code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean `for` rather than `foreach`. You should also stop `key` being global and use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`:

```
if(properties != undefined)
{
    for (var key in properties)
    {
        if (properties.hasOwnProperty(key) {
            dialogProperty[key] = properties[key]; // fixed this variable name too
        }
    }
    alert(dialogProperty.close);
}
```

NB Incorporated [Kobi's fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401322/looping-through-object-in-javacsript/7401354#7401354) too.

Comment: or use `Object.keys(properties).forEach`

Comment: @Raynos If you assume ECMAScript 5, yes. I'm not 100% convinced the OP is at that stage...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're trying to copy all properties, you're probably looking for:

```
dialogProperty[key] = property[key];
```

`dialogProperty.key` is not dynamic, it sets the `key` property each time, the same way `dialogProperty["key"]` would.

Answer (score 2):

```
properties && Object.keys(properties).forEach(function(key) {
  dialogProperty[key] = properties[key];
});
console.log(dialogProperty.close);
```

The `properties &&` check is to ensure that properties is not falsy.

The `Object.keys` call returns an array of all keys that the `properties` object has.

`.forEach` runs a function for each element in the array.

`dialogProperty[key] = properties[key]` set's the value of dialogProperty to be that of properties.

Comment: Funny how different the browsers can be in their optimizations. http://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-hasownproperty +1 for this approach, but I'd just clarify that `Object.keys` only returns enumerable keys, which of course would be desired here.